# using directive inside a templateUrl attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive defined in angular, which function look like this:

```
function(){
  'use strict';
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   replace: 'true',
   scope: {reusableScope: '='},
   template: '<div>' +
               '<cool-directive></cool-directive>' +
             '</div>',
};
```

**coolDirective** is an outside directive, that is working fine in this setup. But at the moment that I put my template in a .html file and call it throught **templateUrl** attribute, the directive the was defined inside the template just stop working at all.

```
function(){
  'use strict';
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   replace: 'true',
   scope: {reusableScope: '='},
   templateUrl: 'template.html',
};
```

being **template.html** this:

```
<div>
  <cool-directive></cool-directive>
</div>
```

Why this is happening and how to fix this issue? is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I think it should be `cool-directive`

Comment: Check your browser console to make sure that the template file is actually being loaded? I've never seen template vs. templateUrl make a difference if the content is the same.